# SQLAlchemy custom boolean

Tags: oracle, types, sqlalchemy, boolean

I have an Oracle database with boolean logic implemented this way:

```
MYCOL NUMBER(1,0)

0 = False
-1 or 1 = True
NULL = None
```

With a default SQLAlchemy boolean column, -1 table value doesn't match `False` or `True`.
Is it possible to create an SQLAlchemy custom type that maps such a column to a bool python attribute?

The difficulty relies in having multiple values associated with `true`.
Ex:

```
session.query(User).filter_by(active=True)
```

Should generate one of these queries:

```
select * from user where active != 0;
select * from user where active in (-1, 1);
select * from user where 1 = (CASE WHEN active != 0 THEN 1 ELSE active end);
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation seems to work for basic queries.
`Case when` expression seems to be the easiest solution because operator logic isn't altered.

```py
class CustomBoolean(sqlalchemy.types.TypeDecorator):
    """0 = False
    -1 or 1 = True
    NULL = None
    By default, SQLAlchemy only supports 0 and 1"""

    impl = Boolean
    cache_ok = True

    # In select or group by clause, replace col with expression: (CASE WHEN col != 0 THEN 1 ELSE col end)
    def column_expression(self, col):
        expr = col.expr
        if isinstance(expr.type, CustomBoolean):
            res = sqlalchemy.case(
                (type_coerce(expr, Integer()) != sqlalchemy.literal_column("0", type_=Integer), sqlalchemy.literal_column("1", type_=Integer)),
                else_=type_coerce(expr, Integer())
            )
            return type_coerce(res, Boolean())

        expr.type = Boolean()
        return expr

    # In where clause, replace col with expression: (CASE WHEN col != 0 THEN 1 ELSE col end)
    class comparator_factory(Boolean.Comparator):
        def operate(self, op, other, **kwargs):
            op1 = self
            if hasattr(op1, "__clause_element__"):
                clause = op1.__clause_element__()
                if isinstance(clause.type, CustomBoolean):
                    op1 = self.normalise(clause)

            op2 = other
            if hasattr(op2, "__clause_element__"):
                clause = op2.__clause_element__()
                if isinstance(clause.type, CustomBoolean):
                    op2 = self.normalise(clause)

            return op(
                op1, op2, **kwargs
            )

        @staticmethod
        def normalise(expr):
            res = sqlalchemy.case(
                (type_coerce(expr, Integer()) != sqlalchemy.literal_column("0", type_=Integer), sqlalchemy.literal_column("1", type_=Integer)),
                else_=type_coerce(expr, Integer())
            )
            return type_coerce(res, Boolean())
```

Comment: There is a strange behavior with `limit` + `distinct` + `oracle`: https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/8217